# Is there a length limit on how long an Apache environment variable can be?

Tags: apache, http, environment-variables

Is there something similar to LimitRequestFieldsize that applies a length limit to environment variable?

In other words, can one set environment variable value arbitrarily long or it will be truncated at certain limit? If there's none, is there any practical concern of setting a too long environment variable?

Thanks!

*I know this could be a better question on ServerFault but due to really unpopular traffic on that site there always seems to be a higher chance a question gets answered here even though it's supposed to be more appropriate on another site...